# Is it possible to deploy Docker containers using Netflix's Spinnaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, spinnaker

I wonder if Spinnaker (http://spinnaker.io) can be used for docker container deployment?

What we do is:

1. Poke the repo
2. If the code is new there - we build 3 containers (nginx, django app container, fluentd logger container)
3. we are spinning up fluentd container in order to collect the logs from the rest 2 containers and send it to Splunk/AWS Cloudwatch Logs
4. we want to spin up django app container, on the same host - nginx container (as a proxy to Django container) [and forward the logs into fluentd ]
5. we forward (map) the certain json file with the app configuration ito the django container

Unfortunately Spinnaker has too few examples, the example they have [here](http://spinnaker.io/documentation/hello-spinnaker.html) shows only how to bake the image with the certain DEB package inside.

We do have jenkins jobs which can poll the repo, test the code, create and upload the docker container into the private registry and deploy the containers using ansible. The question is if we can use Spinnaker in order to do that natively?

Answer (score 5):

there is currently no container support in Spinnaker. Google is actively working on adding Kubernetes support. But there is currently no plans to integrate Spinnaker directly with either docker or ecs.

Comment: Just curious as to the reasons as to why there are no plans to integrate Spinnaker with docker or ecs. It would seem a natural progression for microservices to be deployed in containers instead of VMs. Are there reasons as to why Netflix is not moving in this direction?

Comment: Netflix is moving towards containers via the Titus effort. http://www.slideshare.net/aspyker/netflix-and-containers-titus .

Comment: Has anything changed? Is a container deployment supported by Spinnaker? I thought I read sth. about that on the spinnaker page but cannot find it anymore. I'm trying to understand if spinnaker is a viable CD solution for on-prem kubernetes cluster.

Comment: @kenJoyner Lookout has added ECS support to Spinnaker.  See https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver/tree/master/clouddriver-ecs for instructions on how to set it up

Comment: Titus from netflix was just open sourced and this also is supported in spinnaker

Answer (score 0):

One thing we tried and worked was to use Jenkins to build and publish a debian wrapper for the docker image that was created. All that this debian does is to pull and start the docker container for a spinnaker service. We then created a spinnaker pipeline that bakes this debian and then deploys it.